# When I try to insert ip2long Integer, the wrong Integer gets inserted into table

Tags: php, mysql, ip

My code:

```
$ip = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'][0]); // Gives an IP address string. Example: "176.10.99.207"

$ipL = ip2long($ip); // An integer, which for this example would be 2953470927.

if( $stmt_insert_ip = $ip_link->prepare("INSERT INTO dataTable(ip,datetime) VALUES(?,?)") ){
  $stmt_insert_ip->bind_param('is',$ipL,date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
}
```

But when I check my MySQL table, the newly-inserted value under the `ip` column is 2147483647, which is "127.255.255.255".

When I run `echo($ipL);`, however, I get 2953470927.

What the H-E-Double hockey sticks is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have used `INT` as datatype in your database. To make this story short just change datatype of `ip` column to `BIGINT` and problem will be solved.

```
INT range (-2147483648, 2147483647)
BIGINT range (-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807)
```

2953470927 goes bit over the range of signed `INT`.

Refference: [MySQL: Integer types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately depending on your system (32-bit vs 64-bit) PHP returns different values.

on a 32-bit system it uses signed integers, and on a 64-bit machine it uses unsigned integers, so you'll need to store the data accordingly.

Based on what you returned it seems like you're using a 64-bit machine, so change your mysql column to an unsigned integer, or a signed or unsigned bigint